# Perl - Outputting error code from a channel

Tags: perl, ssh, channel

I am creating a perl script that creates a channel using net::SSH2 within TeamCity. 
I am able to get my command to execute, but I am not able to get the channel to properly log and return an error code to cause TeamCity to fail if something doesn't go right.

I have tried many different variations, but here is my current code.

```
$chan = $ssh2->channel();
$chan->blocking(0);
$chan->shell();
$exitCode = 1;
print $chan "/usr/bin/dos2unix /nfsMount/tomcat/cronScripts/*.sh\n";
while (<$chan>)
{
    print "dos2unix utility successful.\n";
    $exitCode = 0;
}
```

I'm not really understanding how this channel thing works. Based on what I read [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=568568), it seems that you need some sort of tied filehandle after you execute your code. My code executes, but never gets inside that while block. I have also tried variations like:

```
$chan->exec('/usr/bin/dos2unix /nfsMount/tomcat/cronScripts/*.sh');
print "dos2unix successful" while <$chan>;
```

to no avail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For just executing a single command checking the return status, [Net::SSH2::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/REMI/Net-SSH2-Simple/lib/Net/SSH2/Simple.pm) Looks a good deal simple. I recommend trying it instead:

```
use Net::SSH2::Simple;

my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2::Simple->new();
{
    my ($stdout,$stderr, $exitcode) = $ssh2->cmd( "uname -sr" ) or die "cannot execute uname: $self->error";
    if ($exitcode == 0) {
            print $stdout if $stdout;
            print $stderr if $stderr;
    }
    else {
            print $stderr if $stderr;
            die "uname failed with exit code $exitcode";
    }
}
```